# WCF wsHttpBinding Security Error

Tags: wcf, wcf-security

I have a WCF hosted in a Windows Service and running with user domain account.

All my clients (Console applicatio or Web Applications) in the domain work very well.

I have a console application that is not in the domain that does not work.

Herei is the error :

```
Exception non gérée : System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityNegotiationException:
L'appelant n'a pas été authentifié par le service. ---> System.ServiceModel.Fau
ltException: The request for security token could not be satisfied because authe
ntication failed.
```

Here is the WCF Server config :

```
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="TransactionalBind" transactionFlow="true"/>
      </wsHttpBinding>

[...]

    <endpoint address="http://machine.domain.fr:1083/MyService/"
              binding="wsHttpBinding"
              bindingConfiguration="TransactionalBind"
              contract="MyService.IMyService"/>
[...]

    <behavior name="MyBahavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="True" />
      <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647" />
    </behavior>
```

Here is my client config :

```
        <wsHttpBinding>
            <binding name="WSHttpBinding_IMyService" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
                openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
                bypassProxyOnLocal="false" transactionFlow="true" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
                messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="true"
                allowCookies="false">
                <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
                    maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00"
                    enabled="false" />
                <security mode="Message">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" proxyCredentialType="None"
                        realm="" />
                    <message clientCredentialType="Windows" negotiateServiceCredential="true"
                        algorithmSuite="Default" />
                </security>
            </binding>
        </wsHttpBinding>
[...]

        <client>
            <endpoint address="http://machine.domain.fr:1083/MyService/"
                binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_IMyService"
                contract="wsArchi.IMyService" name="WSHttpBinding_IMyService">
            </endpoint>
        </client>
```

Can you help me please ?

Many Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Try using BasicHttpBinding... 
I was facing issues when i used WSHttpBinding....
BasicHttpBinding solved my problem.!!!

Comment: BasicHttpBinding isn't encrypted!